# Model simple social network in Azure table service

Tags: azure-storage, social-networking, nosql

What is the best table design for a simple social networking website using Azure Table Service?

1. The website could have millions of users.
2. Users need to be able to view a list of all other users in the system sorted by the number of mutual connections.
3. Users must be able to view a list of their connections
4. User must be able to view content posted by themselves and their connections.

One major design constraint is that Azure table service queries are generally limited to the partition key and row key when there are a large number of records or else they get really slow. Another constraint is that query results are only sorted by the partition key and then the row key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Design:

**UserTable**

---

**PK**: GUID  ( GUID for PK will maximize scalability, only one partition with single row in each server)
**RK**: GUID
... Rest of properties

**UserFriendsTable**

---

**PK**: UserTable.RK  ( Every User with his friends in a separate server)
**RK**: GUID
**FriendWith**: UserTable.Pk - UserTable.RK (Concatenate PK and RK from user table separated with "-", this will help you to execute point query fast when you try to access friend profile )

**PostsTable**

---

**PK**: UserTable.RK + "-" +YYYYMM+ Random number (This will allow azure to put all monthly posts of any user in a separate server. Random number to prevent azure from auto grouping partitions in sequence. You can query posts with filtering PK partly ex: pk start with XCtghi94ktY-201411.
**RK**  use following code to generate row key in descending order. means latest post comes first.

```
 long ticks = DateTimeOffset.MaxValue.UtcDateTime.Ticks - DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime.Ticks;
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            string suffix = "-";
            string.Format("{0:d21}{1}{2}", ticks, suffix, guid);
```

**Post** : String

Comment: Thank you for your response back in February. It has taken me several months before I learned enough that I’m finally starting to understand your answer. I decided to swap around the PK and RK in the PostsTable. I used “DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks” thinking that this would better load balance the queries and so that I wouldn’t have to sort the query results. I used the UserTable.RK as the PostTable.RK.

Comment: My code looks like this:
var microblogCondition = string.Empty;
              foreach (var UserFriends in lstUserFriends) 
microblogCondition += "RowKey eq '" + UserFriends + "' or ";
microblogCondition = microblogCondition.Remove(microblogCondition.Length - 3);

var microblogDynamicTableEntities = microblogTable.ExecuteQuery(microblogTableQuery.Where(microblogCondition))
                                                                        .Skip((pageIndex - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize)
                                                                        .ToList();

Comment: However, when I run the query will millions of records in the table, it takes more than 5 minutes to return the results. I am thinking of switching the keys around like you have them, but I had two questions if you wouldn’t mind sharing.
1. Why is the query so slow for the design above?
2. If I switch the keys, why not just use UserTable.RK as the PostTable.PK and “DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks” as the PostsTable.RK?
3. If I were to use “UserTable.RK + "-" +YYYYMM+ Random number” as the PK, how do I know which partitions to query in order to return the user’s posts?

Comment: sorry for reply late as i am not following SO. I see you are not query by partitionkey, and this will affect the performance. rule no 1 is to use partitionkey in any query to avoid getting data from multiple cluster. redesign your table and queries like that and try again.